# How to calculate all fees to get exact price or profit on wealth simple stocks

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, calculation, fees

I'm trying to calculate all the fees in a trade for a buy and sell, from me being in Canada (CA). So this is for buying or selling a CAD stock or a US stock. I have some theories but wanted to check if there are any mistakes. So far my findings are as follows:

According to this, there is a currency conversion fee for converting USD <-> CAD of a fixed 1.5% fee.

https://help.wealthsimple.com/hc/en-ca/articles/1500003651222

According to this, there is a "spread" fee that is always applied even if you trade a stock in the same currency as you.

https://help.wealthsimple.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115010155528-Are-there-any-other-fees-besides-the-Wealthsimple-fee-

It also mentions a 0.035% fee, but I'm not sure if that's something additional?

I also noticed for crypto, there is an operational fee (that appears random each time) that the app tells you about when trading. Is that the same as the spread?

The above link mentions "Fund Management Fee", what is this exactly, and does this apply to trading stocks?

Finally, there are forex values wealthsimple has at anytime, which at one point were these values:

```
buy_rate: 1.2523
fx_rate: 1.2336
sell_rate: 1.2151
spread: 0.015
```

Now from the first link above, the foreign exchange rate (fx_rate) is the exchange rate and currency conversion fee combined. But I read that the stock always sells at the market rate. See number 2 here:

https://help.wealthsimple.com/hc/en-ca/articles/360056580234

So does it mean, instead of fx_rate, we would use the buy_rate when buying and sell_rate when selling?

To put it all together:

If I'm from Canada and buying a CA stock, the total price is:

```
(1+spread) * (1 + 0.00035) * (1 + 0.0019) * (ask_price) * (number_of_stock)
```

If I'm from Canada and buying a US stock, the total price is:

```
(1+spread) * (1 + 0.00035) * (1 + 0.0019) * (ask_price) * (buy_rate) * (number_of_stock)
```

If I'm from Canada and selling a CA stock, the total profit is:

```
(1-spread) * (1 - 0.00035) * (1 - 0.0019) * (bid_price) * (number_of_stock)
```

If I'm from Canada and selling a US stock, the total profit is:

```
(1-spread) * (1 - 0.00035) * (1 - 0.0019) * (bid_price) * (sell_rate) * (number_of_stock) / (1 + 0.015) * (1 - 0.015)
```

*note that fx_rate is the exchange rate and currency conversion rate, but I'm assuming sell_rate is the same thing but just at a market rate. So if I then divide by 1.015, it removes that added 1.5%, and leaves it at just the exchange rate, then I multiply by 0.985 to then deduct the 1.5% to get the actual profit I would make.

*and for cryto, there is an added operational fee

If anyone could help verify, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is "CA"? Canada or California?

Comment: Sorry, it is Canada

Comment: The answer to this is completely dependent on your broker.  You should have received and read a document outlining fees and on-charges when you opened your account.  If it's not clear you should ask them.